# Read n, Find the value of M where M = 2 * 4 * 6 * … * ≤ n

Tags: java, for-loop

`n` is any integer value, given by the user. `M` is Multiply of all even  numbers in  `1..n`:

```
M = 2 * 4 * 6 * … * ≤ n
```

Example :

```
int n = 9
```

output

```
 int output = 2*4*6*8; // 384
```

My code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)

int n=inut.nextInt();

for(....)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and give it a try. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: It seems like you need someone to write your homework. Where you are stuck, which part you need help with?

Comment: Can you please clarify what is N and M ? and your sample code and also expected input and output.

Comment: In addition to what T.J. Crowder suggestes, please try to map out how _you_ as a human would do that calculation for various inputs. That way you should be able to see a pattern or algorithm that you then could express with code. If you're running into problems with either task please specifiy what those are and why you're running into them.

Comment: `M = 2 * 4 * 6 * … * ≤ n` is very *similar* to `M = 1 * 2 * 3 * … * ≤ n`, which is known as the algorithm named [**factorial**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial), and there are a gazillion examples on the web for how to write that in many difference programming languages, so I suggest you do some **research**, and go find some of those examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you need to multiply all even numbers between 1 and n.

For this you can use a for-loop and if-statement. for-loop will give you all numbers between 1..n, and if-statement will reject odd numbers, leaving only even.

Last path would be to multiply all values.

```
int n = 9;// input;

int result = 1; // because you are multiplying, initial result must be 1
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   if (i % 2 == 0) { // ignore all odd numbers
      result *= i; // multiply result with next even value
   }
}
System.out.println(result); // print the result: 384
```

You can look at this like an assembly line. At the start someone is generating numbers from 1 to n. Then someone called '*the filter*' rejects (push to trash) all odd numbers, at the end of the line someone called '*the aggregator*' multiplies all values into an result.

With Java 8 and streams this can be represented by:

```
  int result = IntStream.range(1,n)// generate numbers from 1 to n
               .filter(value->value%2==0) // reject all odd numbers
               .reduce(1, (a,b)-> a*b); // multiple all values, with 1 as initial result
  System.out.println(result);
```